# Why does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag> only show one question per page?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When I try to search on the tag `[travis-ci]`, the results are given as only question per page.  This happens with any tag, e.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby

etc.

Comment: Set the page size to some number other than one then.  It's configurable.

Comment: 1 per page isn't a standard option (15,30,50 are), but if you edit the URL, you can change it to anything.  It also remembers your last setting, so if you accidentally changed 15 to 1 in your last search, your next search will only return 1 per page until you change it again.

Comment: "you can change it to anything" - up to 50.

Answer (score 6):

The server remembers the last page size you used for search pages. You can set the page size by clicking one of the "common buttons" (15, 30, 50) at the bottom of the page, or by appending the following to your url:

```
&pagesize=xxx
```

So, in your example, to see a single question per page for [travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci):

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci?sort=newest&pagesize=1

You can do the same thing to fix this, either manually change the `pagesize` variable in the url or click the common page size buttons. Remember this value will be shared across all search pages.

---

Now, if that didn't help you, we've truly got a (unreproducible) bug.