# Default page size when searching is 1 instead of 15/30/50

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, pagination

I first noticed it earlier today at work, and now on my system at home, that the page size when searching defaults to 1 now. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 shows me 1 question per page.

Has this happened to anyone else? Was the default page size perhaps set to 1 by accident?

Comment: Brilliant - wasn't just me then - noticed that about 4 hours ago. It started working after a bit though. I noticed that none of the page sizes were selected as normal (15 is the default). If you click one of those and do another search I think it works again though. Kind of smells like a cookie/local storage problem. (Wonder if there's been any changes recently to remember the page size for searches - think I've seen that requested a few times - just wildly guessing though)

Comment: Does 1,262,706 holds anything special? No? Just me? Ok.

Comment: I noticed this earlier as well this morning, brought it up [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44634777#44634777) to see if anyone else experienced it at the time

Comment: Yes, I had this issue a like 6-7 hours ago and was writing out a question and found a dupe, let me see if I can find it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag> only show one question per page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273237/why-does-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-tagged-tag-only-show-one-question) or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298861/meta-stackoverflow-questions-are-now-limited-to-one-per-page

Comment: It doesn't seem reasonable to me for a bug report that's confirmed by several people as a *recent change in function* to close it as a duplicate of another bug report from 3 or 4 years ago, even if the issue is superficially similar. Clearly, something has changed such that there's an issue that's being experienced by multiple people. In addition, the two proposed duplicates appear to be issues for individuals, not for multiple people. OTOH, the work-around/personal solution that's offered in both proposed duplicates does solve the problem for each individual, but not the systemic issue.

Comment: Reported on Meta.SE: [Questions per page broken on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318753/289905).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the build going out now, is no longer possible to set page sizes outside 15, 30, and 50 (1-50 was valid before). The page sizes are validated before going into your user preferences and on the way out for anyone already affected/stored with an invalid value. Given the default page size is 15, the most a malicious user can do is change it between the 3 valid values (greatly lowering the appeal of such an attack).

It's not a perfect solution, but it gets most of the way there without making simple paging far more complicated. We have some ideas of how to better solve this long-term (e.g. maintain the status quo for fetching a page but beacon API the page setting...but such approaches are fundamentally more complicated and more error prone. I'm not sure such potential issues are worth the tradeoffs.

I'm very curious on thoughts though - comments here would help on next steps. I'm calling this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as the annoying pagesize=1 attack is no more.

Answer (score 11):

Clicking on desired page size again to fixes the issue.

Looks like a bug - probably someone changed how this value is stored. I have low expectations for quick root cause or fix as there is Thanksgiving in US :)

Comment: Converted Jon Clements into answer so everyone have workaround. Feel free to delete if/when official answer is posted.

Comment: Not sure if Jon wants to be converted ... maybe his comment does ... ;)

Comment: @rene maybe if I was converted to **the** answer I could live with that... But since we all know that's 42 it'd be a little pointless - we'd still need to know what **the** question is :p

Comment: @jonClements : Wasn't that the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything..  Lets see if someone finds a way to convert a complex biochemical organsim to a 8bit integer ;)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to hold the last value you use. Asking for `?pagesize=4` will hold that value as default for pagination.

That's my favourite <del>bug</del> rogue feature of the week, I must say.

Comment: Agreed, and if you haven't used Search for some time, it defaults to `pagesize=1`. After I used a `15` or `30` option, it sticks with that from then on. Looks like it's either a Session value or stored as a user 'preference'.

Comment: "rogue feature", I'm stealing that.