# Search only shows 6 results, but no pagination

Tags: bug, status-planned, tag-search

Note that I have the "Custom Question Lists" beta turned on in my SO preferences; people without this enabled might not see this bug.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=mostlinks&filters=today&pagesize=15 (warning, this will reset your default search page size to 15)
2. Observe that only 6 results are listed, and the controls to change the page size and current page disappear

### Expected:

I see 15 search results and the pagination elements.

### Result:

I only see 6 search results, and there are no errors in my browser console

### Browser:

Chromium Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

### Screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Works for me... Any chance you have some custom extensions installed (`userscript.html` is somewhat suspect in the stack trace)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The error in my console was caused by a userscript, but even disabling all extensions, the error remains, without any errors in my console now

Comment: Is this a bug? I'm thinking that "most links" only shows questions that have at least one question linking to them (i.e. questions that show up in the "linked questions" sidebar). When you limit that to only questions asked *today*, I wouldn't be surprised this is all there is.

Comment: @laurel I came on the above page from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=mostlinks&filters=today&pagesize=1 where I do have the pagination elements in the bottom, it seems like a bug to me that they re suddenly gone by changing the amount of items on a page, if I change the number of items on a page, I expect the remainder part of the page to stay, and not parts of the page randomly getting removed

Comment: @Ferrybig 6 pages of results with 1 per page = **6 total**. The controls are never shown when the results can fit on one page, not even with the old nav and it has nothing to do with tags either ([example](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured)).

Comment: Isn't that related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376950/10465355?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be by design, but that design will be going away.  I guess [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) is the appropriate label.

You're getting 6 results because that's the number of questions that met your criteria.  You're asking for c# questions that were both asked today **and** are link to or are linked to by other questions.  Since brand new questions are unlikely to be linked to, you're only getting those questions with links to other questions.  (I believe this is how we count links.)

There are two changes coming with regards to this:

- Date filtering is going away because it is confusing and often the meaning people want to project onto it is not feasible in our querying system.
- I'm renaming "Most links" to "Most linked" because it is a little clearer.  This is a synonym for "Frequent" or "FAQ", and without a date filter it'll get you a bunch of canonical versions of common questions.

Comment: How nice that the community user reminds us of these changes still to come by bumping this question!